# __repr__ for Exception derived class not works well

Tags: python, inheritance, exception, repr

I tried to use `__repr__` method on object that inherit from Exception.

but nothing was printed!

Can anyone help explain why?

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyException Object"


try:
    raise MyException()
except MyException as e:
    print(e)   # shows nothing!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `MyException` is inheriting `Exception.__str__`, which is what is first consulted by `print` (because the implicit call is to `str(e)`, which only falls back internally to `__repr__` if `__str__` doesn't exist.

Curiously, `Exception.__str__` returns a blank string:

```
>>> str(Exception())
''
```

I suppose playing around with it, it returns whatever is passed to `Excpetion` as an argument

```
>>> str(Exception(1))
'1'
>>> str(Exception(None))
'None'
>>> str(Exception(None, True))
'(None, True)'
```

So override `__str__` instead. Or better yet, in addition to:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyException Object"
    __str__ = __repr__
```